# JavaFX Module not found

Tags: java, javafx

Im working on a javafx project , but when Im trying to run it , apparently compiler cant find the modules , well probably ? I search a solution for this but they're all different and nothing helped , this is the message I get :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\java.exe" --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52563:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -m DesktopApp/sample.Main   
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module DesktopApp not found
```

I forgot to mention , in case it helps , I use Intellij 2020 edition , javafx sdf 15.0.1 / jdk-15 / jre1.8.0

Comment: The error occurs while executing `java`, so this isn't a compiler error. You're launching the application with `-m DesktopApp/sample.Main` and the error is telling you it can't find the `DesktopApp` module. That's likely because you don't include your compiled module on the `--module-path`.

Comment: Also, how are you using JRE 1.8 if you're developing with Java/JavaFX 15? JavaFX 15 requires at least Java 11 to run.

Comment: @Slaw
I fixed the module path problem , only this is remaining : 
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized: C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\src.zip

Comment: @Slaw I think JavaFX 15 is compatible with JRE 1.8 , it only requires a high JDK version I think

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, JavaFX 11-15 is compiled with Java 11. That means it requires at least a Java 11 runtime lest you get a `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. And keep in mind a JDK is a superset of a JRE (i.e. the JDK is a JRE just with development tools included). As for your new error, I've never come across that before and I don't know why it would consider `src.zip` as a potential module. I suppose one solution is to simply move that file to a different location.

Comment: @Slaw ye I tried , I even saw an old post but It didn't work , as soon as I move or remove the src.zip I get tons of errors